# Create a TypeScript Record where the second type argument depends on the first one?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define in TS a type for an object that maps a string (let's call it `key`) to a function where one of the arguments is always the `key`.

What I currently have is a record that has a `string` for K and a function for the value, like so:

```
const IsCountry: Record<string, (name: string) => boolean> = {
  "US": (name) => true,
  "Caracas": => (name) => false
}
```

Which works fine, but I want to see if I can narrow it down further by making TS figure out that the `name` in the function should only be they `key` string so that the type checker would throw a warning or error if I try to pass it anything else:

```
IsCountry["US"]("Caracas"); //SHOULD error out, but it doesn't
```

That call does not error out under the current design since the argument for the function can take any `string`.

Thank you!

Comment: you want `IsCountry["US"]("US");` to be ok, and error for other param? Is this what you really need?

Comment: This *does* sound like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). If you are getting something by property name as in `IsCountry["US"]` you *should* already know what this property is. Why would you need to repeat the same string as a parameter to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible by using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types). But we need to have a type which will represent possible keys. Below I've created union of string types - `Countries` and type is narrowed, so function needs to be called only with the exact key.

```
type CountryRecord<A extends string> = {
  [Key in A]: (x:Key) => boolean // mapped key - function argument needs to match the key
}
// type which defines all countries keys
type Countries = "US" | "Caracas";

const IsCountry: CountryRecord<Countries> = {
  "US": (name) => true,
  "Caracas": (name) => false
}
IsCountry["US"]("Caracas") // error
IsCountry["US"]("US") // correct
```

Also if defining static list is a problem, then we can create a type from existing structure, maybe you have some object with keys of these countries. Below example of such structure which can be our blueprint for the type:

```
const Countries = {
  "US": "United States of America",
  "Caracas": "Caracas"
}

type Countries = keyof typeof Countries; // type created from existing structure
// now the same usage:

const IsCountry: CountryRecord<Countries> = {
  "US": (name) => true,
  "Caracas": (name) => false
}
```

### EDIT

As @jcalz correctly mentioned in the comment it is possible to achieve this effect by identity function which will correctly apply the type. Consider:

```
type CountryRecord<T> = { [K in keyof T]: (name: K) => boolean };
const asCountryRecord = <T extends CountryRecord<T>>(t: T) => t; // identity function which applies the wanted type by inferencing the given structure
const IsCountry = asCountryRecord({
    "US": (name) => true,
    "Caracas": (name) => false
});
```

Lets explain how works this identity function:

```
const asCountryRecord = <T extends CountryRecord<T>>(t: T) => t;
```

- `<T extends CountryRecord<T>>` - T is a type assignable to CountryRecord so really it needs to have wanted structure pseudo code - `{key: key=>bool}`
- `(t: T)` - argument is a thing which has type T, so it means TS will do inference on the structure given here and T will equal typeof value in the argument.
- `=> t` - it means the function does not do nothing, only return the same data, that is why I am saying it is only identity in the runtime.

In other words `asCountryRecord` is a tool which enables as to use inference of the argument to fulfill the generic type argument. Solution is equal with previous propositions, but instead of static existing type, type is inferenced from the argument.

Comment: You don't need a predefined type or static list; instead you could use a helper function like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gVwHbAE4gEoQMZ1QEwB4AVAPigF4oBvKAbQGkoBLJKAawhDgDMpiAugC4oACiQBDALYQRDAJSVyAIzhwANhAlsAvgG4AsAChcSAM7AoEs-GRpMOPPkpQSUCAA9gEJPjOxEFHQsXAISUlJRYBFiRQpyYEMTOHNLAEkbQPsXa1sgh1D8UWpjKDKoACIAVQBlCpFxaQg4hNQECAAaUvKKmAlUCWxrerFJGRaoHgl1MwhjHXk9IA).